# postgresql raffle draw query

Tags: sql, postgresql

**goal**
draw first place to fifth place tickets. a user can't win multiple places. If a user hasn't placed, then all of their tickets must be considered in the draw.

**progress**
I can draw one winner, but not all five.

**idea**
I could repeat the query 4 more times and eliminate the previous user_ids each time. But there's got to be a better way.

**question**
how do I draw all 5 place tickets?

**tickets table**

- id
- user_id
- amount
- created_at

**this is my query**

```
WITH gen_tickets AS (
    -- Use `generate_series()` to create a row for each ticket
    SELECT user_id, amount, created_at
    FROM tickets
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, CAST(amount AS INTEGER))
),
shuffle AS (
    SELECT user_id, amount, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY random()) AS rn
    FROM gen_tickets
)
SELECT * FROM shuffle
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Try using a window function to assign a unique rank to each ticket, while ensuring that no user wins more than once.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com how would I use the unique rank. The tickets already have a random row_number.

Comment: If you already have a random row number assigned to each ticket and want to draw five unique winners such that a user can't win multiple places, you can use a window function like DENSE_RANK to ensure each user is only selected once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate_series` to create one roll of the dice per ticket.  Then select the five users with the highest rolls:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  user_id
        ,       max(random()) as roll
        FROM    tickets
        CROSS JOIN
                generate_series(1, amount) gs(num)
        GROUP BY
                user_id
        ) s
ORDER BY
        roll DESC
LIMIT   5
```

[Example at DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CdmN_ncE)

Comment: love the simplicity of your answer. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to actually spawn the tickets and select from among them. The `amount` already dictates the probability: [demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/xlPS1h0R)

```sql
select row_number()over(order by random()::numeric^amount::numeric),
       user_id 
from tickets 
limit 5;
```

Addressing [@Andomar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50552/andomar)'s [remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77752084/postgresql-raffle-draw-query/77752378#comment137074240_77752378) on the [initial version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77752378/2) of this, [here's an additional set of tests](https://dbfiddle.uk/3VMnRbYB) showing the current version offers adequate probability.

Comment: I wonder if `amount*random()` skews the result towards larger amounts?  Say one user has one ticket and another two tickets.  The first gets one roll from 0..1.  The second gets a roll for 0..2.  This gives the second user a 75% chance to win instead of a 66% chance.

Comment: @Andomar You [were right](https://dbfiddle.uk/sGGPA9YD). Fixed&updated now - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

ended up trying what TSCAmerica.com suggested. But it produced duplicates unfortunately.

```
WITH gen_tickets AS (
    -- Use `generate_series()` to create a row for each ticket
    SELECT user_id, amount, created_at, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY user_id
    ) dense_rank_number
    FROM tickets
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, CAST(amount AS INTEGER))
),
shuffle AS (
    SELECT user_id, amount, dense_rank_number, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY random()) AS rn
    FROM gen_tickets
)
SELECT dense_rank_number, user_id, amount
FROM shuffle
GROUP BY dense_rank_number, user_id, amount
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: [See this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3w5MWnHs): it is quite slow and simply incorrect - it keeps repeating selections. The results do not match the probabilities based on `amount`. I wouldn't be so quick to pin that on [@TSCAmerica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77752084/postgresql-raffle-draw-query/77752378#comment137073784_77752084) - they only suggested `dense_rank()` without any details about what they actually had in mind.

Comment: yeah i used Andomar's answer. Didn't mean to blame TSCAmerica though.